# Data Structures review books

Tags: data-structures

I'm planning to take DataStructures course this semester. I had gone through the internet for material related to Data Strucutures. I would like to have an idea on the concepts of data structures before my semester begins. Can anyone suggest me any material or book ?

Comment: my personal favorite is: http://www.barnesandnoble.com/listing/2684382409088?r=1&cm_mmca2=pla&cm_mmc=GooglePLA-_-TextBook_NotInStock_Under26-_-Q000000633-_-2684382409088

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several books which will offer you a great deal of learning . To Name a few,

1.[Data structures and algorithms made easy](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1468108867) - A very good read from an Indian author

2.[Data structures and algorthims](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201000237) by Alfred Aho and Ulman

3.[Fundamental of Data structures](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0929306406) by Horowitz and Sahni

to name a few on learning elementary data structures. Apart from that there are other books which are very good for algorithms. But these books should be enough to give you an introduction.